# Accessing sub-object method via form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model (i.e Person is sub-object of Client):

```
client
  id
  person
    first_name
    last_name
```

Is it possible to access straight away subobject field without opening inner form, e.g?:

```
<%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field 'person.first_name' %>
<% end %>
```

(this, by the way, gives error)

Comment: what do you mean by saying "sub-object"?

Comment: Person is sub-object of client, e.g client.person.first_name = 'Peter'